# SQL query to find record that are not made

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have three tables:

[image]

I able to left join the table to find SALESCATEGORY that made by the salesperson. But how do I create a SQL query so I can know which SALESCATEGORY that the salesperson have not made? In this case,

```
john  C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K
james D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K
```

should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cross join` to generate all rows and then use `left join` (or a similar method) to remove the ones that exist:

```
select sp.*, c.*
from salesperson sp cross join
     salescategory c left join
     salesrecord s
     on s.salespersonid = salespersonid and
        s.salestype = c.salescatid
where s.salespersonid is null;
```